# I can't include a 3rd variable in my iteration properly

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, iteration

I am trying to create an iteration over an image grid with x and y coordinations using Python. This image operation also involves applying an effect represented with parameter "c".

I'm struggling to make this work as intended which is as iteration navigates the grids via steps of 500 px c should also increase by 0.1. But after each row c will reset in my code.

There must be smarter ways to do this but I couldn't figure it out. Can someone contribute? Thanks in advance.

Edit: c was already incrementing correctly in my code and this wasn't the issue. in fact the way the effect works c needed to be reset and accepted answer worked well for that, thank you to all contributors.

```
c=0
for x in range(0,5000,500):
    for y in range(0,5000,500):

        new_img = brightness_filter.enhance(c)
        img.paste(new_img, (x, y))
    c+=0.1

new.show()
```

Comment: To make sure I understand: as `y` increases along a row, you want `c` to increase; and when the new row starts, you want `c` to start over? Well then, can you think of a mathematical relationship between `c` and `y`? Then you can use an expression in terms of `y` to replace `c`.

Comment: @splaytreez please look at the `range`s more closely. There is no need for that.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. Let's say rows and columns go like this:
row 1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
row 2: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ,20]
The goal is that c doesn't reset when it reaches 2nd row. if grid #10 c = 1, for grid #11 c should be 1.1 or whatever the incremental is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, this should be what you are looking for?

```py
for x in range(0,5000,500):
    c=0
    for y in range(0,5000,500):

        new_img = brightness_filter.enhance(c)
        img.paste(new_img, (x, y))
        c+=0.1

new.show()
```

though it'd be easier to define c as a function of y, so something like this:

```py
for x in range(0,5000,500):
    for y in range(0,5000,500):
        c = y / 5000
        new_img = brightness_filter.enhance(c)
        img.paste(new_img, (x, y))
        

new.show()
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your reply. My goal was to continue to increment c (which was already the case with code so wrong debugging on my end) but actually the way you placed c inside the first for loop solved the problem with the effect although it actually resets the c each time second loop concludes. So, i'll mark your answer as accepted.